# Having issue with multiple file downloads

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, nsurlsessionconfiguration

Currently I'm implementing a file download application.
In my application server there are around 2500 Resource files, I need to download those files from server to my document directory.

**My Code:**

```
@implementation DownloadManager
{
    NSURLSession *session;
    BOOL downloading;
}

#pragma mark - NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate

// Handle download completion from the task
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location
{
    NSInteger index = [self assetDownloadIndexForDownloadTask:downloadTask];
    if (index < 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    DownloadHelper *movieDownload = _assetsToDownload[index];

    // Copy temporary file
    NSError * error;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:location toURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[movieDownload localPath]] error:&error];
    downloading = NO;
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didResumeAtOffset:(int64_t)fileOffset expectedTotalBytes:(int64_t)expectedTotalBytes
{
    // Required delegate method
}

// Handle task completion
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"Task %@ failed: %@", task, error);
    NSLog(@"Task %@ Success: %@", task, error);
    if ([_assetsToDownload count])
    {
        [_assetsToDownload removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }

    downloading = NO;
    if ([_assetsToDownload count])
    {
        [self downloadFiles];
    }
    else
    {
        [self downloadAssets];
    }
}

// Handle progress update from the task
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
{
    NSInteger index = [self assetDownloadIndexForDownloadTask:downloadTask];
    if (index < 0) return;
   // DownloadHelper *movieDownload = _assetsToDownload[index];
    double progress = (double) (totalBytesWritten/1024) / (double) (totalBytesExpectedToWrite/1024);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Showing progress
    });

}

#pragma mark - Movie Download Handling & UI

// Helper method to get the index of a Asset from the array based on downloadTask.
- (NSInteger)assetDownloadIndexForDownloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask
{
    NSInteger foundIndex = -1;
    NSInteger index = 0;
    for (DownloadHelper *asset in _assetsToDownload)
    {
        if (asset.downloadTask == downloadTask)
        {
            foundIndex = index;
            break;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return foundIndex;
}

- (void)addAssetDownload
{
    DownloadInfo *info = nil;
    NSString *assetFolder = nil;
    for (int index = 0; index<[_assets count]; index++)
    {
        info                                    = [_assets objectAtIndex:index];
        NSURL *url                              = [NSURL URLWithString:info.assetURL];
        NSURLRequest *request                   = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask  = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request];

        DownloadHelper *assetDownload        = [[DownloadHelper alloc] initWithURL:url downloadTask:downloadTask];
        assetDownload.assetName                 = info.assetName;

        if (info.categoryId == 1)
        {
            assetFolder = [self getImagePath:info.assetName];
        }
        else if (info.categoryId == 2)
        {
            assetFolder = [self getVideoPath:info.assetName];
        }
        else if (info.categoryId == 3)
        {
            //assetFolder = [self getDBPath:info.assetName];
        }
        else
        {
            assetFolder = [self filePath:info.assetName];
        }
        assetDownload.assetFolder = assetFolder;
        [_assetsToDownload addObject:assetDownload];
    }
}

// Initialize the download, session and tasks
- (void)initialize
{
    for (DTEDownloadHelper *movieDownload in _assetsToDownload)
    {
        // Cancel each task
        NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = movieDownload.downloadTask;
        [downloadTask cancel];
    }

    // Cancel all tasks and invalidate the session (also releasing the delegate)
    [session invalidateAndCancel];
    session = nil;

    _assetsToDownload = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Create a session configuration passing in the session ID
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:@"DTEDownloadBackground"];
    sessionConfiguration.discretionary = YES;
    session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    [self addAssetDownload];
    // Reset the UI
    downloading = NO;
    [self downloadFiles];

}


// Download handler
- (void)downloadFiles
{
    if ([_assetsToDownload count] > 0)
    {
        // Acquire the appropriate downloadTask and respond appropriately to the user's selection
        NSURLSessionDownloadTask * downloadTask = [_assetsToDownload[0] downloadTask];
        if (downloadTask.state == NSURLSessionTaskStateCompleted)
        {
            // Download is complete.  Play movie.
            // NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[_assetsToDownload[0] localPath]];
        }
        else if (downloadTask.state == NSURLSessionTaskStateSuspended)
        {
            // If suspended and not already downloading, resume transfer.
            if (!downloading)
            {
                [self showHUD:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Downloading %@",[_assetsToDownload[0] assetName]]];
                [downloadTask resume];
                downloading = YES;
            }
        }
        else if (downloadTask.state == NSURLSessionTaskStateRunning)
        {
            // If already downloading, pause the transfer.
            [downloadTask suspend];
            downloading = NO;
        }

    }
}

- (void)downloadAssets
{
    _assets = [self retreiveAssets];    // Getting the resource details from the database
    if (![_assets count])
    {
        // Hide progress
    }
    [self addAssetDownload];
    [self downloadFiles];
}
@end
```

**Issue :**

Sometimes it downloads the first file and stops there, on next time onwards it is not downloading anything. I couldn't find the issue till now, I wasted almost a day because of this issue. Please help me to find the issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using background sessions, old download requests can persist from session to session. Have you tried checking for old, outstanding background tasks with `getTasksWithCompletionHandler`? I had a bear of a time until I realized that when my app starts, it can get backlogged behind old background requests. And if you have any invalid requests sitting in that background session, everything can get a little backed up.

Also, is your app delegate handling the `handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession` method, re-instantiating the background session and saving that `completionHandler` that is passed to your app? And is the `delegate` of your `NSURLSession` calling that completion handler (presumably in `URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession:` method)? You want to make sure you clean up these background sessions. I don't see any this method in your code snippet, but perhaps you omitted it for the sake of brevity.

A discussion of this can be found in the *Background Transfer Considerations* section of the [URL Loading System Programming Guide: Using NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW44) guide. Also example of this is shown about 40 minutes into the WWDC 2013 [What’s New in Foundation Networking](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=705) video.

Answer (score 0):

Using `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` was a mess to me. So finally I implemented a custom download manager using `NSOperationQueue` and `blocks`.

I have added this library to [GitHub](https://github.com/Midhun-MP/MMP_DownloadLibrary).